# MYSQL stopped - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, ubuntu-20.04

I've reinstall Xampp 7.4.6, everything running well but MYSQL doesn't work, it's stopped. I reinstalled third time after removing everything (even folder).
Also following error comes up when I write mysql -v in terminal.

```
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'kash'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: if you want to see the version it must be a big "V" :))  like `mysql -V`

Comment: The server is running, else there could not be Access denied error

Comment: ok, right mysql -V

Comment: Yes server is running, but my question my MYSQL database stopped, it happens now otherwise I first time installed xampp everything was working well